# Turning LED ON/OFF while using Tkinter using Arduino

Tags: python, tkinter, led

```
enter code here

from tkinter import* 
import serial
import time
ArduinoUnoSerial = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
print(ArduinoUnoSerial.readline())
#Create Serial port object called ArduinoUnoSerialData time.sleep(2)                                                             #wait for 2 secounds for the communication to get established
#read the serial data and print it as line 

print ("You have new message from Arduino")
one = '1'
one_byte = str.encode(one) #This will convert this into a binary code since the Arduino cannot read in strings.
zero = '0'
zero_byte = str.encode(zero)

def Set_Led():
    while 1:
        var = Set_Led()                          #get input from user             
    if (var == '1'):                                      #if the value is 1         
            ArduinoUnoSerial.write(one_byte)                  #send 1 to the arduino's Data code       
            print ("LED turned ON")         
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        var = Set_Led()
        if (var == '0'):                                   #if the value is 0         
            ArduinoUnoSerial.write(zero_byte)               #send 0 to the arduino's Data code    
            print ("LED turned OFF")         
            time.sleep(1)

win = Tk()
win.title('Turn the LED ON/OFF')

Box_1 = Entry(win, width = 5)

Label = Label(win,text = 'How do you want the LED?').grid(column = 1, row = 3)

Box_1.grid(column = 2, row = 3)

Button1 = Button(win, text ='Okay', command = Set_Led)

Button1.grid(column = 2, row = 4)


win.mainloop()
```

I've had trouble receiving the interger to place it into my Entry box in order for the Okay button to operate. I get errors such as RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. I want to be able to create one function that will turn the LED ON/OFF yet i wanted to know why my function isn't allowing for the interger that needs to be placed in the grid to turn on when 1 is placed. I've tried setting the var to Box_1 and Button1 but i've received errors such as positional argument missing. Any help or tips would help Thanks.

Comment: So, you have a function named `Set_Led()` in which the first thing you do is call `Set_Led()` an infinite number of times - how were you expecting that to work?  I would suggest doing this in a much simpler way - get rid of the Entry, have two Buttons that turn the LED on and off respectively.  The `command=` function of each button would only need a `.write()` call, nothing else.

Comment: My assignment requires me to have only one button, so that's where im stuck as i am only supposed to use the okay button. I agree with my function and how off it was. This program will be done in Tkinter, so i'm assuming it needs an entry.

Comment: @JustinPaul: Remove the `while 1:` and both `var = Set_Led()`. Initalize `global var = 0`. On `ON` do `var = 1` on `OFF` do `var = 0`.